# share link and image by UIActivityViewController Swift issue

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to add in my app sharing with socials and other apps , for this reason I added `UIActivityViewController` in this way:

```
var url : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://maps.google.com/?ll=\(self.text1),\(self.text2)")

   let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["test" , self.uiimageViewPhotos.image! ,  url], applicationActivities: [])
        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My problem is that when I share , for example using Facebook , it shares only image and the text that I insert when `UIActivityViewController` appears , but not the link ( `url` )

where do I wrong?

Comment: I see the words sharing and Facebook, sadly Facebook have stopped apps sending text through for people to share which is really annoying. This happened a few months ago now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose either sharing an image or a URL, both together won't work. And just as a reminder, the text you are passing in has to be written by the user sharing the message, character by character, do not pre-fill anything here to avoid trouble.

Comment: I want to share a photo and together it text inserted by user and a link. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can't, you either share a message from the user with a photo or a link but not with a link and a photo. However you can host the image on a website and then have the user share the link to that site, type in their message and set the image you link to as the og:image in the HTML